# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-epojkmk3/duckdb/

Tags: python, mindsdb

I'm trying to set up mindsdb in local(visual studio code) with (python version 3.7) using

```
pip3 install mindsdb
```

command but facing an error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-epojkmk3/duckdb/
```

How do I resolving this error?

Comment: Can you try `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` ?